# Access-Control-Allow-Origin missing, Microsoft Speech-to-Text JavaScript API

Tags: javascript, text, cors, speech

I am trying to use Microsoft Speech-to-Text JavaScript API. It does not work. I get the following:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/sts/v1.0/issueToken. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).

Any ideas?

Comment: can you show me the code you are using to make the request?

Comment: Is the site you are calling the API from also https:// ?

Comment: you probably want to send your request to your server, get the data from API and send it back to browser. Do you realize, that if you send the request directly from the javascript the user can see your app-secret-key?